# How to use __range in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

```
class Order(models.Model):
     customer = models.ForeignKey('Customer' , on_delete=models.SET_NULL , null= True , blank = 
      True)
     date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

I have this in order model .
Now I want to take order.objects.filter and take only data whose date_ordered is between today and 7 days before

Comment: I'm not really following. `date_ordered` is always between `date_ordered` and `date_ordered + 7 days`.

Comment: Can you explain *what* you want to achieve (instead of *how* you want to ahcieve it)?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem , can you please review the question again , i have edited again .

Answer (score 0):

You can filter with:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db.models.functions import Now

Order.objects.filter(
    date_ordered__range=(
        Now()-timedelta(days=7), Now()
    )
)
```

If you want to match with the date, and thus not 24×7 hours ago, you can work with:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils.timezone import now

today = now().date()
before = today()-timedelta(days=7)

Order.objects.filter(
    date_ordered__date__range=(
        before, now
    )
)
```